# Comparing pairs of arrays in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, hash

I've got multiple pairs of Arrays.
The first of the pair contains multiple strings.

The second contains a timestamp belonging to the string at the same position of the first array.

Here are two pairs of arrays for an example:

```
#String array
M681
T9997
E61
H717
K700

#Timestamp Array
11:00
11:05
11:05
11:10
11:15
```

The second pair of Arrays would look like this:

```
#String array
B722
T732
L999
M681
I125

#Timestamp Array
11:00
11:00
11:05
11:10
11:15
```

I want to find matches where a string is in two pairs and  then i want to measure the time difference between both entries.

Comparing the string-arrays was simply done by `(Compare-Object -IncludeEqual -ReferenceObject $a_string -DifferenceObject $b_string -ExcludeDifferent).InputObject`, but with this i couldnt compare the responding timestamps.

So my next idea was forging each pair together in a hashtable:

```
$hash = @{}
$hash.Add($a_string[$i],$a_timestamp[$i])
```

But i noticed that this would not work in my enviroment since both the strings and the timestamps could reoccur in one array, so setting one of them as the key of the hash would not be possible.

Next I tried creating a hashtable with an array as value and an index as key:

```
$hash.Add($indexNumber,@($a_string[$i],$a_timestamp[$i]))
```

Even though `$hash.indexNumber` prints out both values, i cant seem to get on of the values by `$hash.indexNumber[0]` / `$hash.indexNumber[1]`

I would appreciate if someone could tell me the best practice with this kind of situation or could tell me how I can successfully get the seperate Values of the array inside the hash and compare them to other array values in different hashes.

Kind regards,
Paxz.

Comment: What information are you working with that it's not structured in a type meant to deal with it and is instead just some array of arbitrary information?

Comment: What does the actual data in each array look like? Please post samples by editing your question.

Comment: Also, completely without any idea what the data looks like (since you didn't show an example) I'm going to bet that the write Powershell answer is going to involve custom objects...

Comment: @EBGreen added an example of the string and timestamp array.

I tried working with Custom Objects, but couldnt find a way solutions that didnt had the same problems as the hastable

Comment: Except for `11:05` nothing in your example data actually matches anything else.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: `$hash[$indexNumber][0]` and `$hash[$indexNumber][1]`

Comment: @EBGreen sorry, I thought an example of on pair of arrays would be enough. I will add an better example now

Comment: So in the example you would want to know that M681 had a time of 11:00 in the first set of arrays and a time of 11:10 in the second set and that the time difference was 10 minutes?

Comment: @EBGreen Yeah thats exactly what i want to know.

Comment: Well, first of all matched arrays are a horrible way to hold data. Where does the data come from? Is there a way to get it into a more structured data type? For instance a hash of arrays comes to mind.

Comment: @EBGreen well the arrays are combine columns of an excel sheet.
The excel sheet is structured like this:

`<timestamp>;<characterOfString>;<numberOfString>;<emptyColumnAsSepeartorForNewArrayPair>;<timestamp_b>;<chara....`

The timestamps dont start at the same position in each pair of arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is a relatively naive solution and will probably need some work to properly handle edge cases, but hopefully it will get you going in the right direction:

```
$arrayNames1 = @('M681','T9997','E61','H717','K700')
$arrayTimes1 = @('11:00','11:05','11:05','11:10','11:15')
$arrayNames2 = @('B722','T732','L999','M681','I125')
$arrayTimes2 = @('11:00','11:00','11:05','11:10','11:15')

function Find-AllIndexesOf{
    param(
        $array,
        $term
    )
    $i = 0
    foreach($item in $array){
        if($item -eq $term){
            $i
        }
        $i++
    }
}

foreach($name in $arrayNames1){
    if($arrayNames2.Contains($name)){
        $array1Locations = Find-AllIndexesOf $arrayNames1 $name
        $array2Locations = Find-AllIndexesOf $arrayNames2 $name
        $i = 0
        foreach($location in $array1Locations){
            $thisTime1 = [datetime]$arrayTimes1[$array1Locations]
            $thisTime2 = [datetime]$arrayTimes2[$array2Locations[$i]]
            Write-Host ('I found a time difference for {0} that started at {1} and ended at {2} for {3} total minutes' -f $name, $thisTime1, $thisTime2, ($thisTime2 - $thisTime1).TotalMinutes)
            $i++
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though i get alot of errors talking about Variables set to NULL and other couldnt convert to [DateTime], I checked the output and its seems right!
Thx alot for all ur efforts!! I will go and try to debug the errors now.

Comment: Yeah, that would be the part about the solution being naive and needing work to handle edge cases. :)

Answer (score 0):

> But i noticed that this would not work in my enviroment since both the strings and the timestamps could reoccur in one array, so setting one of them as the key of the hash would not be possible.

I am unclear on why a simple hashtable does not work in your use case.

```
$table = @{}
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $a_string.count; $i++){
  if(!$table.Contains($a_string[$i])){
    $table.Add($a_string[$i], @())
    $table[$a_string[$i]] += $a_timestamp[$i] 
  }else{
    $table[$a_string[$i]] += $a_timestamp[$i]
  }
}
```

This would generate a table mapped with Strings to times which could then be used to compare against other pairs.

Comment: Because my array features multiple entries which reoccur while i still have to add them and their timestamp into the hash, but the hash would either need the string or the timestamp to be the key.
For example we could have two entries "B433" in one array with different timestamps, i couldnt add both entries to the hash as I can only add the string with the name "B433" once as primary key.

Comment: In the provided spinet it attaches timestamps to duplicate string entries to the same key.

Essentially this maps each unique key and maps it to an array of associated values. The resultant map would look something like:

`B722    {11:00,11:05} `